# Editext.setSelection with Seekbar Android

Tags: android, android-seekbar

Hi， I'm facing an issue with `EditText` and `SeekBar`.

**Problem**
When dragging the Seekbar it will send progress to `EdiText` which is common behavior, but when I'm trying to clear which is pressing the clear button the `EditText` will only clear 1 digit, how could it clear all digits like normal `EditText`? Much guidance appreciate thanks :)

Example:
My `EditText` is showing 1000, if I tapped and hold the Erase button the result will be 100 then nothing happens but what I wanted is 100,10,1 and cleared, it's possible to do that? and how can I do it?

```
mSbTest = findViewById(R.id.sb_testing);
mEtTextSize = findViewById(R.id.et_text_size);

    mSbTest.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            mEtTextSize.setText(String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));
            mEtTextSize.setSelection(mEtTextSize.getText().length());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });

    mEtTextSize.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                setEditTextMaxLength(mEtTextSize, 9);
                mCustomBarChart.TextSize(Integer.valueOf(s.toString()));
                mCustomBarChart.invalidate();
                mEtTextSize.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                mSbTest.setProgress(selectedValue);
                selectedValue = Integer.valueOf(s.toString());
                mEtTextSize.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: why you have added mEtTextSize.addTextChangedListener(this); in afterTextChanged?
Dont set listener in afterTextChanged.

Comment: Hi @Mundroid, if i did not add mEtTextSize.addTextChangedListener(this); when I type the value in editext field Seekbar will not goes to position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue myself and kindly refer to below code for future reference. Also thanks Avinash for tips and ideas. Cheers :)

```
 mSbTest = findViewById(R.id.sb_testing);
 mEtTextSize = findViewById(R.id.et_text_size);

    mSbTest.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, final int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
                mEtTextSize.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
                Selection.setSelection(mEtTextSize.getText(), mEtTextSize.length());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });

   mEtTextSize.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                setEditTextMaxLength(mEtTextSize, 9);
                mEtTextSize.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                mEtTextSize.requestFocus();
                mSbTest.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(s.toString().trim()));
                mEtTextSize.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this one, it's working perfect

```
    sikbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
           if(i>0){
                editText.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                editText.setSelection(String.valueOf(i).length());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

In onTextChange Use this

```
  @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                   if (!editable.toString().isEmpty()) {
                        int progress = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(editable.toString()));
                        sikbar.setProgress(progress);
                    }
                    else {
                        sikbar.setProgress(0);
                    }
```

//this listener is only for erase all text on single tap.
    enter code here

```
     editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            //You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                //this is for backspace
                  mCountDownTimer.start();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

In onTextChange Please check size of input , else it throws exception.

add timer for one by one clear text after few sec and start timer first on keylistener.

```
  CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer(global variable);

    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(1200, 1000) {
        boolean mText=true;

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            String mainText = editText.getText().toString().trim();
            if(mainText.length()>0&& !mText){
            String text=mainText.substring(0, mainText.length() - 1);
                editText.setText(text);
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
                mText=true;

            }

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            String mainText = editText.getText().toString().trim();
            if(mainText.length()==0)
            {
                mCountDownTimer.cancel();
                mText=true;
            }
            else{

                mCountDownTimer.start();
                mText=false;
            }

        }

    };
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206436/discussion-on-answer-by-avinash-editext-setselection-with-seekbar-android).

Comment: Hi @Avinash, I've tested your code. Your answer is almost correct but the problem is it will continuous to clearing all text when I've released my finger from the Backspace button which is wrong as well. My goal is when I tapped once it will remove 1 digit at a time and when I hold or long press it will remove the digits one by one. Do clarify with me again if you are still confused with the question